# Small CLI-only distribution based on Arch or Debian

Tags: linux, arch-linux, distribution-choice, small-distribution

I've looked at a lot of topics that look like what I'm looking for but aren't quite what I want. To give you some context, my ultimate goal is to have a Vagrant box that can compile some C code and output a binary. These are my requirements :

- The OS image needs to be very small (around 50 MB would be good enough, the smaller the better)
- Ideally I don't want to compile every tool I'd like to use, so it would be nice if I had access to the Arch or Debian package repos through pacman or apt-get
- All I need on the base image is a toolchain, basic networking, and a popular package manager

The idea is for this base image to be complimented with other specific tools using Packer and then packaged as a Vagrant box.

So far I've looked at these distros :

- Tiny Core: Very interesting size-wise (10 MB) but the package repo makes it a no-no, and I haven't seen anything on getting pacman on it.
- Arch Linux: The base image is very large for my needs (>600 MB). I might be able to create a custom image, but this is a last resort.
- Puppy: Tahrpup is based on Ubuntu but still big for my taste (200 MB)
- Alpine: 82 MB, good enough but again the package manager makes it a no-no

Comment: No idea how big this turns out to be - https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian

Comment: You may have a look at http://linuxbbq.org/about.html

Comment: Try debian live-build tools. You can customize you own image and build it.

Comment: You can just use Arch's [archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) to have whatever packages you want installed on the live media.

Comment: @HalosGhost, this is the path i'm currently investigating, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, I think you like Arch. Well, it is easy to create a custom image using `mkarchroot`. See this example:

```
$ mkarchroot -C pacman.conf img packages
```

where

- `pacman.conf` is your pacman config file
- `img` is a directory to contain the files
- `packages` is the list of packages you'd like (e.g. start with `base grub`)

You can then write the contents of that `img` directory onto a filesystem that you can boot from. You'll need to setup a bootloader (i.e. `grub`) which I won't go into here.

You may need to refine your package list to get a working system that is suitable for your needs but this should get you started. Also, you don't need all of `base` for a minimal working system so you can trim out packages that you don't need (list required packages explicitly and omit `base`).

If you need to, you can download a vanilla `pacman.conf`:

```
curl https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/pacman.conf.x86_64?h=packages/pacman > pacman.conf
```

(my example above generates a filesystem that is 5.5G in size)